# Не отображается элемент с id=trigger

Tags: javascript, веб-сайт

Есть input при нажатии на который должен появится блок и при повторном нажатии скрыться:

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 text-center">
                <input type="image" id='trigger' src="../core/css/logotip/logotip.png" class="logotip_icon" title="Меню"/>
            </div>
      
 
 
 




<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#trigger").toggle(
    function() {
      $("DIV#box").fadeOut();// Скрываем блок
      return false;
    },  

    function() {
      $("DIV#box").fadeIn();// Отображаем скрытый блок
      return false;
    }
  );
});
```

Но что-то происходит и самому input добавляется display:none, где я допустил ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Но что-то происходит

https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Происходит то, что Вы самому инпуту делаете `toggle`.

```js
$("input#trigger").click(function(e) {
  $("DIV#box").toggle(1000);
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="trigger" value="Click" />
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: если заменить toggle на click то при нажатии на input ничего не происходит...(

Comment: @HistoryLifeNSK Все происходит.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, все получилось, единственное плавная анимация не срабатывает(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать`width` и `height` для `input` в css:

```
#trigger{
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: не помогает, input все также невидим(

Comment: Что значит "Попробуйте"? С какой целью?